# Socket.io Multiplayer Rooms - Deleting user data only when user leaves the entire domain

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to create a lobby for a multiplayer game where players can join rooms similarly to how the game "Among Us" does it. My original approach included storing the "socket.id" of every player as they load into the website. However, when I eventually redirected them to a room, the id refreshed. To counter this issue, I began using cookies to store an id for every user. This works great, but there is one issue I cannot seem to fix.

I am looking for a way to trigger an event only when the user leaves the entire domain. It should not be triggered when the user is being redirected to a different website path under the same domain. I would like to use this in order to erase any data stored (their username and cookie id) in a server-side array that contains user data. The main reason for this is to make sure that the information about the user remains if they are just being redirected to another site.

I tried using the socket.io "disconnect" event, but the problem with that is not only does it fire even when redirecting between subpages, but it also restricts me from being able to pass the cookie id. I've also tried using an approach like "onbeforeunload", but for whatever reason, the socket.emit is never received by the server, probably because the connection is disturbed before the request can be made. I also didn't quite understand how to get and compare the target and current domain within the event function.

I'm not sure what code would be useful, but [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/fire-typhoon-millennium?path=public%2Fhome.html%3A70%3A16) is my glitch project if you want to take a look at it.

I am open to any kind of work around.

Comment: I don't think you can reliably tell when a user leaves your website or just loads another page in it. Unless your app IS a single page.